# Changing default font for \mathcal in “Pages” equations

Tags: pages, latex

I recently asked a [question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/576754/changing-default-font-for-mathcal-in-pages-equations-mac?noredirect=1#comment1452117_576754) on TEX StackExchange but thought it would be more appropriate to ask it here.

I am using Pages version 10.3.5 (7029.5.5). Typing in TeX environments in Farsi is an absolute pain even though the output is fine so I was writing in Pages. My problem is, I want to type this "F" in an equation:

[image]

But `\mathcal{}` gives me fancy RSFS characters like this:

[image]

The default font for `mathcal` is the Computer Modern one everywhere else. Though I read in jksoegaard's answer in this [question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/378657/does-pages-support-latex-extensions) that Pages doesn't support installing LaTeX packages, I wanna know if I can manage to get the font I want.

Comment: You should have asked for the first question to be migrated here rather than cross-posting to both stacks.

Comment: Not sure if this is possible. If not and you find the LaTeX support within Pages to be a bit too limited, I suggest checking out [LatTeXiT](https://www.chachatelier.fr/latexit/latexit-home.php?lang=en).