# Install new LaTeX packages in Keynote, Pages

Tags: keynote, iwork, latex

I was trying to make a presentation in Keynote since it had a direct LaTeX equation writer embedded. However, I soon realised that some of the commands (and therefore packages) were not supported. I've searched online and it seemed that the only possibility would be to add equations as a PDF. But I was wondering if there is a way to install new packages directly in the blahTeX used in Keynote or, even better, make Keynote use the MacTeX I've installed.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apple didn’t [ship a fully configurable TeX / LaTeX stack](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/378658/5472) - they just implemented some of the most common items.

You may wish to get your full install going if the apps don’t perform to your needs.

- https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/378658/5472